# Methods to create a dotted complex shape. is it possible or do I need to use another tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, illustration, drawing, illustrator-effects

I see illustrations like this and wonder how to create something like this (see the example below). What tool should I use? Is there a lesson on how to create one?[image]

Comment: Well obviously you dont need a anything you dont allready have after all nothing stops you from drawing each dot manually. But yeah this was clearly done in a 3D app of somekind.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do in Blender. I will give a brief overview.

**Option 1, use Geometry Nodes (better solution)**

1. With object selected, open Geometry Node Editor, Add Geometry Node Group to the object and name it whatever you want.
2. Create the following node group, you can press "Shift + A" to search for the node.

[image: Node Group]

The node group adds a subdivision surface multiplier to add more geometry (vertices/points). Merge by Distance will remove vertices that are too close together.

The Mesh to Point and Instance on Points makes it so the Ico Sphere is instanced everywhere there is a point. Set Material adds a material shader to the geometry.

Values for each node option will depend on the scale of your object.

**Result**

[image: Render]

**Option 2, Turning vertices into cylinders**

The following idea is adding a sphere wherever there is a vertices point.

1. If your object has low amount of vertices, I would suggest adding a Subdivision Surface Modifier to add more detail. Then apply the modifier
2. Go into edit mode in your object, select all points. Delete and choose Only Edges and Faces. You're left with just the vertices.
3. With the vertices selected, Press E (to extrude), then S (to scale) and type ".99". You're extruding each vertices by 1 more, the .99 is the distance. Exit out of Edit mode.
4. With the object selected. Convert mesh to curve by going to Object -> Convert -> Curve
5. Under Object Data properties -> Bevel, add Depth and make sure Fill Caps is selected.

Comment: suggest adding a slightky inwards nudged copy to make backface culling

Comment: @joojaa, added a better option, if using Blender, then Geometry nodes is the way to go.

Comment: or just filter non-visible faces https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268532/20102